# How to Loop NSThread?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsthread

I am curious to know if you can loop an NSThread for the iphone sdk. I have learned that instead of using NSTimers which do run off of the main UI, I can use NSThreads to run actions in the background. Most of  my NSTimers have the "repeats:" to YES, thus I need to know if NSThreads can be looped.

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Please be more explicit. What are you trying to achieve ? Can you add some pseudo-code to describe it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) loop {
    while (!finished) { … };
}

- (void) startThreadedLoop {
    finished = NO;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loop)];
}
```